# Directory to place files on windows

Tags: windows, windows-permissions

on linux when we have a foothold and we want to transfer files to the victim we usually transfer it to `/tmp` beacuse it is writable and always there.
what directory should we transfer our files if we compromise a windows machine which is usually writable and always there ?

Comment: The user's temp directory - `%tmp%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Thank you @VenVen for pointing out the \Windows\Temp dir!

The system-wide temp directory on Windows is `%SystemRoot%\Temp` (C:\Windows\Temp, typically). You can also use the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` (which is almost always C:\ProgramData on modern Windows versions). The ACLs on both directories are very similar to the *nix Sticky directory permission bit as set on `/tmp`: all members of the "Users" group (so, anybody except anonymous users and guests) are allowed to create files and directories within the directory itself (or any subdirectories you created), but only the owner of a file or directory can access it once it's created (by default; the owner can of course modify the ACLs to grant access to others).

A few differences:

- \Windows\Temp does not allow read privileges (for non-admins) within itself, meaning you have to know the path to the file or directory you're opening without listing directory contents. This might be inconvenient but it also makes it harder for a non-admin to see your files.
- ProgramData is a hidden directory (merely an advisory flag, equivalent to a *nix dotfile), but does allow listing by normal users and a ton of stuff gets put there by, which may make your additions not stand out.

For that matter, the ACLs on the root of the system drive (C:\) are similar, though more restricted; you must create a subdirectory rather than putting files directly under the root, and only Authenticated Users have this permission (meaning it might not work if impersonating a user without their credentials). It is more likely to be obvious to a user, of course.

You can also check the `%TMP%` (or %TEMP%) environment variables for a user-specific temp directory. This might not be set, or not set usefully, for non-interactive service accounts or other situations, though.